# How widespread, used is CWL, common workflow language?

Tags: pipeline, workflow, apache-airflow

Trying to get an overview of different languages and software for workflows and data pipelines--and thus 'data engineering'--I stumbled upon [Common Workflow Language](https://www.commonwl.org/). I thought, well, how common is this? - Got to ask the community, and I hope DevOps is appropriate.

Does someone know how used this language is? Perhaps compared to Apache Airflow or other tools for workflows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question is almost certainly going to be closed "off-topic", but since I have some experience with communities using CWL in the past, I'll provide my bit.

First, a correction to your premise: CWL is a *standard*, which makes it different to most other [workflow tools](https://github.com/common-workflow-language/common-workflow-language/wiki/Existing-Workflow-systems). It has several implementations. One of the main benefits is that it's platform-agnostic, making workflows highly-portable.

As you can see [from their website](https://www.commonwl.org/gallery/), the user community of this standard is heavily biased towards research communities. [Implementations](https://www.commonwl.org/implementations) of the standards are de-facto default toolchains in several smaller communities, mostly in the bioinformatics domain, where workflows can become quite complex.

There is a strong incentive to publish workflows so that

1. workflows can be attributed correclty
2. reproducibility can be tested.

If you want to use Apache Airflow, there's an [implementation of CWL for that](https://github.com/Barski-lab/cwl-airflow)

Comment: Thanks a lot (OMG, the number of alternatives). Do you mind expanding a bit on comparisons with the alternatives? Perhaps 'implementations of CWL _for_ a given tool' and "plain" CWL without needing the additional ones? - that is, if such a question makes sense. Otherwise, please state that such a way is not useful for reason a,b,c. :-)

Comment: I think you'll find that at https://www.commonwl.org/implementations/